# Enable multithreading Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, c++11

I have been trying to get a program working in Eclipse C++. One of the functions uses multithreading from std. Here is the function in the code:

```
void PrimeCheck::checkFull(long long int number)
{
    std::thread t1(&PrimeCheck::checkFirstHalf, this, number);
    std::thread t2(&PrimeCheck::checkSecondHalf, this, number);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

When searching for a solution, I came across many solutions, all of which stating to either add a -pthread flag or a -std=c++11 in addition to changing the dialect to C++11. All of which I have done. This is what the compile command looks like in eclipse so you can see exactly which modifications I have already added:

```
Building file: ../src/Prime Checker.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++0x -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11  -pthread -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive -MMD -MP -MF"src/Prime Checker.d" -MT"src/Prime\ Checker.d" -o "src/Prime Checker.o" "../src/Prime Checker.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Prime Checker.cpp
```

And this is the linker command as it appears in eclipse:

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -Wl,--no-as-needed -pthread -shared -o [A bunch of .o files]
```

The code compiles correctly, and eclipse content assist recognizes thread as a member of std. Yet, when I run the program I still this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
```

To test this, I wrote a simple program outside of Eclipse which looked like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func1(int x){
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        cout << " " << 1 + i;
    }
}

void func2(){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        cout << "Standard message! ";
    }
}

int main(){
    int input;
    cout << "Give me a number:" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    thread t1(func1, input);
    thread t2(func2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();


    return 0;
}
```

And compiled it in the terminal with this:

```
g++ ThreadTest.cpp -o Program.o -std=c++11 -pthread
```

And the program ran without error. I think this means that there's something wrong with Eclipse, but I'm not sure.

As a note, I'm doing this on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc version 4.8.4. Also, I know that similar questions have been asked, but as far as I can tell, I've implemented those solutions with little success.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The first suspicion is that version of g++ called by Eclipse is not the same as the one used when you call g++ from command line.

Comment: How would you verify that the gcc versions are the same? In the terminal you can do `g++ --version`, but what about in Eclipse?

Comment: Check your toolchain settings.

Comment: The Tool Chain Editor only mentions that it is using "Linux GCC"

Comment: But what does that mean? ;) What are the executables used?

Comment: The executable uses files from gcc 4.8, so while it may not be the exact same version, but the terminal and Eclipse use 4.8.*

Comment: Are you sure all .o files are compiled with `-pthread`? Can you remove -std=c++0x -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__?

Comment: I did, but the outcome is the same. And as far as I can tell, all the .o files compile with -pthread.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? An answer would be useful, if so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Using **Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers v4.7.3a** in **Ubuntu 14.04**.

## 1/2. Problem description

Just trying to run this sample code:

**mutex.cpp**:

```
// mutex example
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex

std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section

void print_block (int n, char c) {
  // critical section (exclusive access to std::cout signaled by locking mtx):
  mtx.lock();
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { std::cout << c; }
  std::cout << '\n';
  mtx.unlock();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread th1 (print_block,50,'*');
  std::thread th2 (print_block,50,'$');

  th1.join();
  th2.join();

  return 0;
}
```

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/

It builds and runs just fine on the command line with the following command, but **will not run in Eclipse!**

Command-line command that builds and runs in a terminal just fine:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -save-temps=obj mutex.cpp -o ./bin/mutex -pthread && ./bin/mutex
```

Eclipse error when I try to run it in Eclipse:

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'  
>   what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
> ```

## 2/2. The solution to make it build and run in Eclipse is as follows:

### A. Enable pthread for compiler:

Project --> Properties --> C/C++ Build --> Settings --> GCC C++ Compiler --> Miscellaneious --> type in `-std=c++11` to the "Other flags" box, and check the box for "Support for pthread (-pthread)". See yellow highlighting here:

[image]

### B. Enable pthread for Linker:

Then, withOUT closing this window, also set this setting for the Linker:
in center pane: GCC C++ Linker --> General --> check the box for "Support for pthread (-pthread)", as shown here:

[image]

Click "Apply and Close". It will now build and run.